# How to change Ubuntu server domain name?

Tags: webserver, localhost, hostname

I'm using Ubuntu server in my local network. I access the hosted sites on it from other computers using the local ip address. for example: 192.168.100.2/info.php/. I want to set a domain name to use it in the local network so i can access the sites like this: domain.dev/info.php/.

Comment: It depends, where do you, and the "other computers" get their address resolution from? Look at `/etc/resolv.conf (on each)`,`man 3 resolver`, `man 5 resolv.conf` and `man 8 resolvconf`. Or, you could cheat, and add `192,168.100.2  server server.localdomain` to all the `/etc/hosts`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply had to do the DNS configuration on my router and then I was able to access the domain from all devices on the network.

Comment: There's rarely anything simple about DNS configuration. Perhaps you could add some details for those of use who still can't read minds?

Answer (score 2):

if you are doing this in organization where you want to access this url anywhere in private network then configure DNS.

if you just doing in local system and want to access from a specific hosts then you can do this by `/etc/hosts` file

open `/etc/hosts` file using

```
sudo gedit /etc/hosts
```

then do entries like

```
192.168.100.2  domain.dev  hostname
```

also mention ip and FQDN on all system's `/etc/hosts` where you want to access . so , all system know each other.

Comment: So what you're saying is, adding the domain to hosts file won't let me access that domain from other devices on the network? Then how do i do it? You mentioned configuring DNS. How do I do that?